# In report, not show the updated data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, ms-access-2003

I got a problem in showing report. The system flows like below -

1. Systems insert records in CSV file into a table,A in ms access database by batch.
2. Systems update in another table, B, based on these inserted records.
3. Systems shows a report from this table B.

These three steps are done by a click event. Sometimes this report shows the updated data but sometimes, not. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did table B records get updated?
2. If there are any transactions where they commited before step 3?

Comment: Whatever report shows the updated data or not, table B got updated. Currently I use Thread to sleep for 30 sec. At this time, report shows correctly. However, I worry about number of transactions. Now just two rows updating took. Later, if more than hundard, how? :(